# Siteminder applications

Tags: authentication, cookies, siteminder

i have 2 siteminer applications and both are siteminder protected. Application 2 is launched from Application 1 with Javawcript window.open() and passes some querystring parameters. 
Application 1 siteminder cookie is scoped to the fqdn , lets say app1.mydomain.com
Application 2 siteminder cookie is scoped to mydomain.com
i noticed that once the application 1 authenticates user , application 2 does not authenticate the user.
is this expected ? what can be done to enforce authentication by application 2?

Answer (score 0):

are you able to see the smsession cookie being passed from app1 to app2 in browser? simple way to check is through developers tool in the browser.

Also check what is the scope of cookie domain in your ACO. for interoperatibility between applications in the same domain it should be usually set to 2. for example for app1 and app2 in .mydomain.com cookie domain scope should be 2 and cookiedomain should be .mydomain.com

Most of the time i have seen this kind of issue is due to invalid or no settings in cookie domain or cookie domain scope in ACO.